# Loading a field value without overwriting

Tags: angularjs

I have several fields loaded within a directive call for a page, each of which should be loaded with prepopulated data from either a REST call or Local Storage.

Right now, the mechanism I use loads the field through $scope, but when the page finishes loading, the value itself is never populated. When loaded using a jQuery alter, the value is initalized, and then vanishes on page load. I am not sure what the cause is here, and being fairly new to Angular, I am not sure how to best work around this trivial measure.

The directive form markup is below:

```
<form name="testfield" ng-controller="testfieldApp" ng-submit="verify(testform)" novalidate>
  <input type="text" name="testfield" id="testfield" ng-model='testfield' value="{{TestField}}" required />
</form>
```

The wrapping Controller

```
app.controller('testfieldApp', function ($scope, $window, $http, $localStorage) {
  $scope.TestField = "Test Name";
  //Additional $scope. methods exist for validation and submit, omitted
});
```

Comment: `ng-model` is case sensitive so you are essentially setting the value to undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You only need `ng-model`, but it is case sensitive. `ng-model` will override whatever you have in `value`. Try this instead:

```
<input type="text" name="testfield" id="testfield" ng-model="TestField" required />
```